# Set cookie in passport strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

How do I access the response object in a passport strategy in order to be able to set a cookie with res.cookie? I know how to get the request object but not the response object.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide your existing code to better understand the context of you question? Thanks! :)

Comment: I use the following strategy: https://hastebin.com/unevanuvab.php and I want to be able to access to response object inside the "(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)" function.

Comment: What information is it that you want that's not provided by those parameters?

Comment: I want to access the response object from express.

Comment: AFAIK, the strategies themselves don't have access to express res/req. though you say you have access to the req object, how have you gone about that?

Comment: You can set "passReqToCallback" to true as the doc says. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/. It does not says anyhting about the response tho.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, good question. But I believe it can only be accessed within your express handlers with the authenticate middleware. I don't have any more for you unfortunately, but I'd posit that the response is just not available until the middleware has been completed. Apologies for not being more helpful, hopefully someone else can step in!